# Finding which variable is minimum from Math.min()

Tags: javascript, html

i have 5 variables

`var a=10,b=23,c=45,d=90,e=78;
var min=Math.min(a,b,c,d,e);`

i want to find which variable is minimum without using for loop or if statements??

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "which variable"? Variable's name? And why do you need this?

Comment: Using `Math.min()` as you have will return the minimum value of the 5 variables. Do you wish to find the variable's *name*?

Comment: @ArangaNathan Why do you specifically need the reference for the min value? This could be a case of an XY Problem.

Comment: i just want to display the name of the variable !

Comment: _i just want to display the name of the variable!_ Why exactly? For debug purposes or for end user?

Comment: for front-end purpose

Comment: You definitely have design problem with your code. End user **should not** see (at front-end) such implementation details as variable names.

Comment: @ArangaNathan, please see my answer - pretty sure it does what you're looking for. *However this is very odd and irrational code.*

Comment: I'm testing tat code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, place all the variables in an Object, sort them and then get the first item.

```
var values = { a:10, b:23, c:45, d:90, e:2 }
var smallest = Object.keys(values).sort(function(a,b){return values[a]-values[b]})[0]
console.log(smallest) // "e"
```

Comment: sort iterates more than reduce.

Comment: @NinaScholz sure, however OP was pretty specific about "without using for loop or if statements" - I think the simpler the better in this case. My answer won't be the bottleneck..

Comment: if two values have the same value, the you get only one reference.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work without any loop (array iterators, or for, while) and if statements.

This is a solution with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and an object for the reference.:

```js
var a = 10, b = 23, c = 45, d = 90, e = 78,
    object = { a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d, e: e },
    result = function (o) {
        var keys = Object.keys(o);
        return keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
            if (o[k] < o[r[0]]) {
                return [k];
            }
            if (o[k] === o[r[0]]) {
                r.push(k);
            }
            return r;
        }, [keys.shift()]);
    }(object);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

No if version

```js
var a = 10, b = 23, c = 45, d = 90, e = 78,
    object = { a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d, e: e },
    result = function (o) {
        var keys = Object.keys(o);
        return keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
            o[k] === o[r[0]] && r.push(k);
            return o[k] < o[r[0]] && [k] || r;
        }, [keys.shift()]);
    }(object);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: The  question clearly mentions no if statements and no loops. This isn't really an answer.

Comment: ternary operator is pretty much an `if` statement.

Comment: @brod, no ternary anymore.